# Mat of Size 20x20 gets reshaped to 1x1200 when training kNearest

Tags: android, opencv

I train my Model like this:

```
    // Prepare Training Data
    Mat trainData = new Mat();
    int numWidth = 20;
    for (int i = 0; i < digits.size().height; i += numWidth ) {
        for (int j = 0; j < digits.size().width; j += numWidth) {
            //Mat num = digits.submat(new Rect(j * numWidth, i * numWidth, numWidth, numWidth));
            Mat num = new Mat(digits, new Rect(j, i, numWidth, numWidth));

            // Convert to float data, needed for KNearest
            num.convertTo(num, CvType.CV_32F);

            num = num.reshape(1, 1);
            trainData.push_back(num);
        }
    }

    // Train Model
    model = KNearest.create();
    model.train(trainData, Ml.ROW_SAMPLE, Converters.vector_int_to_Mat(trainLabels));
```

And later I try to predict like this:

```
    Mat number = new Mat(square, new Rect(bounds.x, bounds.y, bounds.width, bounds.height));
    Imgproc.resize(number, number, new Size(20, 20));

    saveImage("digit.png", number, context);

    number.convertTo(number, CvType.CV_32F);
    number = number.reshape(1, 1);


    Mat res = new Mat();
    float p = model.findNearest(number, 1, res);
```

But I get this Exception:

```
E/cv::error(): OpenCV(3.4.3) Error: Assertion failed (test_samples.type() == CV_32F && test_samples.cols == samples.cols) in virtual float cv::ml::BruteForceImpl::findNearest(cv::InputArray, int, cv::OutputArray, cv::OutputArray, cv::OutputArray) const, file /build/3_4_pack-android/opencv/modules/ml/src/knearest.cpp, line 312
E/org.opencv.ml: ml::findNearest_12() caught cv::Exception: OpenCV(3.4.3) /build/3_4_pack-android/opencv/modules/ml/src/knearest.cpp:312: error: (-215:Assertion failed) test_samples.type() == CV_32F && test_samples.cols == samples.cols in function 'virtual float cv::ml::BruteForceImpl::findNearest(cv::InputArray, int, cv::OutputArray, cv::OutputArray, cv::OutputArray) const'
E/MethodChannel#openCV: Failed to handle method call
    CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: OpenCV(3.4.3) /build/3_4_pack-android/opencv/modules/ml/src/knearest.cpp:312: error: (-215:Assertion failed) test_samples.type() == CV_32F && test_samples.cols == samples.cols in function 'virtual float cv::ml::BruteForceImpl::findNearest(cv::InputArray, int, cv::OutputArray, cv::OutputArray, cv::OutputArray) const'
    ]
        at org.opencv.ml.KNearest.findNearest_2(Native Method)
        at org.opencv.ml.KNearest.findNearest(KNearest.java:79)
        at com.wallmann.flutter_sudoku_solver.SudokuSolver.readNumbers(SudokuSolver.java:291)
        at com.wallmann.flutter_sudoku_solver.SudokuSolver.solveChallenge(SudokuSolver.java:46)
        at com.wallmann.flutter_sudoku_solver.MainActivity.lambda$configureFlutterEngine$0$MainActivity(MainActivity.java:48)
        at com.wallmann.flutter_sudoku_solver.-$$Lambda$MainActivity$g3xDyIoaci2vBR5JzA2Kry58MDg.onMethodCall(Unknown Source:2)
        at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:231)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:93)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:642)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6710)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, cv::Exception: OpenCV(3.4.3) /build/3_4_pack-android/opencv/modules/ml/src/knearest.cpp:312: error: (-215:Assertion failed) test_samples.type() == CV_32F && test_samples.cols == samples.cols in function 'virtual float cv::ml::BruteForceImpl::findNearest(cv::InputArray, int, cv::OutputArray, cv::OutputArray, cv::OutputArray) const'
    , null)
    #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:569:7)
    #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:321:33)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #2      _MyHomePageState.takeImg (package:flutter_sudoku_solver/main.dart:46:28)
    #3      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:706:14)
    #4      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:789:36)
    #5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
    #6      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:486:11)
    #7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:264:5)
    #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:236:7)
    #9      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27)
    #10     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:222:20)
    #11     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22)
    #12     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
    #13     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
    #14     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
    #15     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1138:13)
    #16     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
    #17     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:933:7)
    #18     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:273:10)
    #19     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:182:5)
```

Whats interesting is, while training, the `num` Mat I train my model with is: `1*1200*CV_32FC1` but when I predict, my `number` Mat is `1*400*CV_32FC1`. However, before reshaping my Mat, both are of the size 20x20. How can it be, that in training, a mat of Size 20x20 gets reshaped to 1x1200?

Any Ideas?

Comment: Try to transpose `num` after this `num = num.reshape(1, 1);` in training procedure, the size of your training matrix is not correct.

Comment: And its not like that your 20x20 matrix is reshaped to 1x1200. In machine learning you must create database of your training data, in other words you have to put training samples together, so basically it means that you reshape 20x20 to 1x400 and concatenate this 1x400 images together.

Comment: @SaeedMasoomi My training images weren't greyscale, that where the size of 1x1200 was coming from but that didn't resolve my exception. What exactly do you mean by "transpose" the `num`? And yes I'm aware I don't train with one image, that why I concatenate multiple mats together with `trainData.push_back(num)`. But I should be able to predict on just one Mat of Size 1x400 right?

Comment: What is the `trainData` size? Your test image size should be like that too. But it's so strange that your test image is converted to 1x400! Are you sure that it has 3 channels?

Comment: trainingData are multiple images, why should my test image have the same size, it should have the same size as one of the images of the training data, right? And the images are supposed to be of size 1x400, these are greyscale images.

Comment: Yes, Sorry for my incomplete statement, your test image must be equal to 1x1200. And for clarification,do you mean that training image is CV_8UC3 and test image is CV_8UC1? For a quick test you can convert GrayScale image to BGR Image and see the result(CV_GRAY2BGR).

Comment: Why do my test image have to be 1x1200, both my training and test image are greyscale and of size 20x20, so it must me 1x400? And both also are of type `CV_32FC1`  because I convert it like this: `number.convertTo(number, CvType.CV_32F)`. My debugging confirms this, test and train images have the same sizes and same types.

Comment: I have tested this code in c++, It worked for me! So strange that it doesn't work for you. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sf8NcVThf6/

Comment: for me `label size:200 x 1` , `training data size:200 x 400` and `test data size:1 x 400`

Comment: Thank you for your help! I messed up the reference of my model and overwrote it after training. The original problem was, that I was using different color types as described in my first response